# How to bruteforce password from HMAC-SHA256 hash (if you have the key)?

Tags: encryption, hmac, sha-256, brute-force-attack, password-hashing

Short of creating one's own script / program, is there an existing, readily available way of iterating through a list of potential passwords to find which one corresponds to a hash (HMAC-SHA256), assuming you have the key it was generated with? This is in asp.net. For the sake of this question / instance, no salt has been used.

Comment: In the usual way!

Comment: Manually / one at a time..?

Comment: See the Hashcat list https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes

Comment: When I manually compute an HMAC, I get something that looks slightly different from the example(s) listed on that page. For instance, HMAC-MD5 of "password" with a key I've randomly selected equates to 7770cee27a11e85be4f6d3681de31847, but the page wants it formatted (their example): c741db0a2968c39d9c2a5cc75b05370:1234. What is the meaning of the colon / separator and extra characters at the end (or beginning) of the computed hash value?

Comment: I tried finding that out, but it was unclear to me as well. Normally I'd say that it was used as number of iteration for password hashing, but in that case the exact password hashing scheme is missing in action.